# Is polarization charge real?

Tags: polarization

Polarization charge is proportional to the inverse of divergence of polarization.

Is it real?

Are there real charge there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polarisation involves displacement of real charges. If you place a slab of glass in a constant electric field perpendicular to it, there will be negative surface charge density on one side and a positive surface charge density on the other side. There is neutrality away from the surface. At the surface the divergency of the polarisation density gives the value of the surface charge density.

The entire negative charge density shifts with respect to the posive one so that they no longer overlap and neutralise one another at the surface.